# Checkboxes do not work in my custom made module

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have a site made in ASP.NET which I turned into a DotNetNuke module. But now when I try to check the checkboxes it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

add the class "normalCheckBox" to your checkbox and DNN will ignore it. ej:

```
<input  type="checkbox" class="normalCheckBox">
```

Comment: the checkbox is changed with the following file: `Resources\Shared\scripts\dnn.jquery.js`. and as User2683036 said with `normalCheckBox` you can stop this behavior, this also works with `normalRadioButton`

Answer (score 0):

The nice people who made DotNetNuke have a special kind of humor. It turns out that checkboxes used on my site are hidden by DotNetNuke and replaced by an image of a checkbox. The reason behind this is unclear to me.

Just take a look at the HTML:

```
<label style="display: inline-block;">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="copyAllSettingsCheckBox" name="copyallcheckbox" title="Copy all settings" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;">
<span class="dnnCheckbox">
<span class="mark">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAMAAAAoyzS7AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAAZQTFRFAAAAAAAApWe5zwAAAAF0Uk5TAEDm2GYAAAAMSURBVHjaYmAACDAAAAIAAU9tWeEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
</span>
</span>
Include any additional settings.
</label>
```

To fix this I used the code shown below. This effectively cleans up the stuff added by DotNetNuke. Just put it at the end of your javascript.

```
$('.dnnCheckbox').remove();
$(':checkbox').removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: You might look into the issue a bit more, just turning off the DNN functionality wouldn't be the best way to do things in DNN. I have checkboxes in my modules, and they work fine with the DNN functionality replacing them for the UI

Comment: When there is time I will take another look at this. I agree that this is more or less a hack instead of a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar problems.

In my case I am using a dialog/popup, and the cause of the checkbox not working seems to be the z-index being -1 (negative one).

HOWEVER it seems that the z-index of the checkbox isn't always set to -1.

For example, as I have mine in a dialog (popup) box, initially the z-index is set to -1 (which seems to work).
When I open the dialog with a button click, the z-index is set to 1001 (which also, seems to work).

However with the checkbox contained in an update panel, the postback renders the checkbox's z-index back to -1 (which doesn't work, as the checkbox is underneath the dialog box).

**In conclusion** - check if z-index of the element containing the checkbox (recursively) is greater than the checkbox z-index, as this might be the cause of it not working (elements without a z-index seem to work with the checkbox fine).

**Bit of a hacky fix:**
I added some jQuery onload to bring checkbox's z-index above it's parent (in this case the jQuery dialog)

This will get all the inputs with a z-index of -1 within the parent element, and set their z-index 1 above the parent

```
//the id being the parent element that has the higher z-index
function FixInputZIndex(id){
    var element = $('#' + id);

    $('#' + id + ' input').filter(function () { return $(this).css('z-index') < 0; }).css('z-index', element.css('z-index') + 1);
}
```

Comment: Just noted the z-index: -1 part in my input element. I am still using the hack to fix this and I have no clue how to get around this gracefully.

Comment: Are you using a dialog too or does the container element have a higher z-index? I've just added some jQuery onload that looks for any element with a z-index of -1 and makes it 1 more than the container element..

Comment: Yes I am @m.t.bennett; I took a look at the generated HTML, the z-index of my dialogcontainer is 1002

Comment: Yep same as mine - I think this is a jQuery default, however because it HAS the z-index its over the top of the checkbox so can't be clicked

Comment: @ m.t.bennett In my case it is not only the z-index, but also visibility which has been set to hidden. Sadly this was just a prototype, so I won't be touching the code anymore, but I am positive (wrong word in this context ;) ) that I will walk into this one again when I create a module of the production version of the site.

Comment: I haven't run into the visibility hidden problem yet (although mine is flagged as hidden), will note for future